# python argparse - can I use only mutually exclusive optional arguments or is there a better way

Tags: python, command-line-arguments, argument-passing, argparse

I am writing a script that downloads a file from the web, performs some processing and stores the data into a mysql db.

I am using `argparse` for accepting arguments. Essentially, the script will do 1 of 4 things:

1) download a user supplied file name from the web and perform processing/db-insert.

2) download the current most filename based on yesterday's date. I have a cron job that runs this part each night after 2am.

3) do the same as #2 but for an additional file.

4) process a user defined file in the current folder and save it to an output file in the same folder.

The script can only do 1 of the above 4 things. As such, I was thinking I can use mutually exclusive optional arguments as follows:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
group = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group(required=True)
group.add_argument('-f','--filename',action='store',nargs=1,help='Filename to download')
group.add_argument('-b','--bulkfile',action='store',nargs=2,help='Bulk filename to process and save')
group.add_argument('-l', '--load', action='store_true', help='Download current load data')
group.add_argument('-s', '--supply', action='store_true', help='Download current supply data')
args = parser.parse_args()

if args.filename:
    do something
elif args.bulkfile:
    do something
elif args.load:
    do something
elif args.supply:
    do something
else: 
    print "Improper usage. Can only use [-f | -b | -l| -s]"
    return
```

I know this isn't ideal. I would rather let `argparse` deal with the usage part of it. I am looking for an optimal way of achieving my objective. I appreciate the help.

Comment: It seems like since the two responses answer two completely different questions your question is not clear...

Comment: I don't really know what subcommands are but think they could be handy at some point. Your response answered my question best as per my requirements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`argparse` will handle usage for you.  Running your script with no arguments I get this error message:

```
usage: test.py [-h] (-f FILENAME | -b BULKFILE BULKFILE | -l | -s)
test.py: error: one of the arguments -f/--filename -b/--bulkfile -l/--load -s/--supply is required
```

Running with both `-l` and `-s` I get

```
usage: test.py [-h] (-f FILENAME | -b BULKFILE BULKFILE | -l | -s)
test.py: error: argument -s/--supply: not allowed with argument -l/--load
```

The parser automatically handles the error messages for the mutually exclusive arguments for you.

Comment: Thank you SethMMortn! So I can remove the *else* clause from my if block and proceed with what I already have?

Comment: Yes.  You don't have to do anything else.

Answer (score 1):

In the spirit of `svn` or `git` you could use [sub-commands](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/argparse.html#sub-commands).

Comment: Thanks ExP! I will investigate.